# Electron.js how to prevent CtrlShift+ and CtrlShift- from zooming in and out the application content?

Tags: electron

Electron application get's scaled when Ctrl Shift + or Ctrl Shift - buttons are pressed. Is it possible to get rid of those shortcuts?

UPDATE: I found this code snippet [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8793) which worked for me

```
window.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    // disable zooming
    if ((evt.code == "Minus" || evt.code == "Equal") && (evt.ctrlKey || evt.metaKey)) {evt.preventDefault()}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default behavior of input events on the window. When creating the window, you can add this:

```
window.webContents.on("before-input-event", (event, input) => {
        // example this is for reloading the page
        if (input.control && input.code === 'KeyR') {
            event.preventDefault();
            return
        }

        // prevent zoom in/out
        if(input.control && ['Equal', 'Minus'].includes(input.code)) {
           event.preventDefault()
           return
        }
})
```

I'm not including the `input.shift` in the check since the zoom in/out can also be done with just ctrl +/-, so this check handles both cases.

the `event.preventDefault()` is blocking the default behavior. You can also add other checks to prevent their default behavior (as per the example for blocking the reload event)